# How to divide one dataframe row by the value of the row using apply?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I want to do something like this, but it throws an error:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row / row[2] )
```

My input data is the following:

| Index | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8206731245 | 1829 | 8440.19 | 140 |
| 6523960772 | 12452 | 523065.36 | 138 |
| 2546262822 | 14889 | 144067.84 | 138 |

Expected output:

| Index | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8206731245 | 1829/140 | 8440.19/140 | 140/140 |
| 6523960772 | 12452/138 | 523065.36/138 | 138/138 |
| 2546262822 | 14889/138 | 144067.84/138 | 138/138 |

Comment: `df.apply( lamda col: col/df['Col3'])` also works.

Comment: What error does it throw exactly? When I try it, it doesn't error, but the result also isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `apply`, you could use [`div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) on `axis=0` to leverage vectorized division:

```
out = df[['Index']].join(df.drop(columns='Index').div(df['Col3'], axis=0))
```

Or, if "Index" is the index, not a column (and it seems likely that's the case since you index `row[2]`), then you can simply use:

```
out = df.div(df['Col3'], axis=0)
```

If you don't want to specify the column name, you could also use `iloc` to use the location:

```
out = df.div(df.iloc[:, 2], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
        Index        Col1         Col2  Col3
0  8206731245   13.064286    60.287071   1.0
1  6523960772   90.231884  3790.328696   1.0
2  2546262822  107.891304  1043.969855   1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```py
pd.concat([df[["Index"]],df.drop(columns=["Index"]).apply(lambda row: row / row["Col3"] ,axis=1)], axis=1)
```

##### Output

```
Index       Col1        Col2        Col3
8206731245  13.064286   60.287071   1.0
6523960772  90.231884   3790.328696 1.0
2546262822  107.891304  1043.969855 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

[`df.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is done over columns by default. Use `axis=1` to apply over rows.

```
df.apply(lambda row: row / row[2], axis=1)
```

```
                  Col1         Col2  Col3
Index                                    
8206731245   13.064286    60.287071   1.0
6523960772   90.231884  3790.328696   1.0
2546262822  107.891304  1043.969855   1.0
```

(I'm assuming your "Index" column represents the index.)